# How to add a time signature to midi file?

Tags: python, midi

I am trying to add a time signature to a MIDI file in Python.

I have tried to do it using the MIDO & MIDI library but don't know whether it is possible or what the exact code needs to be.

What should the Python code look like to add a time signature?

Currently the midi file looks like:

```
...
midi.Pattern(format=0, resolution=96, tracks=\
[midi.Track(\
  [midi.ProgramChangeEvent(tick=0, channel=0, data=[0]),
   midi.NoteOnEvent(tick=0, channel=0, data=[41, 90]),
   midi.NoteOnEvent(tick=440, channel=0, data=[41, 0]),
   midi.NoteOffEvent(tick=0, channel=0, data=[41, 90]),
....
```

And I need to change it to:

```
....
midi.Pattern(format=0, resolution=96, tracks=\
[midi.Track(\
  [midi.TimeSignatureEvent(tick=0, data=[4, 2, 36, 8]),
   midi.TimeSignatureEvent(tick=0, data=[4, 2, 36, 8]),
   midi.ProgramChangeEvent(tick=0, channel=0, data=[0]),
   midi.NoteOnEvent(tick=0, channel=0, data=[41, 90]),
   midi.NoteOnEvent(tick=440, channel=0, data=[41, 0]),
   midi.NoteOffEvent(tick=0, channel=0, data=[41, 90]),

...
```

Comment: Do you know how to add other messages to a file?

Comment: Yes. For example the following works to add a program change: track.append(Message('program_change', program=0, time=0))

Answer (score 0):

Check out this library called [metronome](https://jythonmusic.me/metronome/) which may assist you.

The documentation on that page includes a function called `setTimeSignature(timeSignature)` . Its description is:

> Set metronome’s time signature (a list, e.g., [4, 4] meaning 4/4).

You can use pass in your desired time signature as a list.

Answer (score 0):

The [MIDO documentation](https://mido.readthedocs.io/en/latest/meta_message_types.html#time-signature-0x58) shows how to create meta messages:

```
MetaMessage('time_signature', numerator=4, denominator=4)
```

Comment: I just needed to import MetaMessage from MIDO and then it worked.  Thanks!